# Use induction and Pascal’s identity to prove that if $n > 1$, then $C(n, 1) = C(n, n-1) = n$

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, proof-verification

So, I did the base case and I get:

**BASE CASE**

$C(2, 1) = C(2,1) = 2$.

$2 = 2 = 2$. Base case holds true.

**Inductive Step**

This is where I'm not exactly sure what to do, using Pascal's rule. I have this so far:

Assume $m$ is a natural number greater than $1$. Must prove for $m+1$, such that:

$C(m+1, 1) = C(m+1, m)$

Using Pascal's rule, $$C(m+1, m) = C(m, m-1) + C(m, m)=C(m, m-1) + 1$$

A few things I'm not sure about. Does $K$ become $n$ in this case (from Pascal's rule), and am I on the right track? No clue what to do next. I'm not allowed to use the factorial formula for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**
The inductive step is $C(m,1)=C(m,m-1)=m$ where $m$ is a natural number greater than one. Next step will be to prove that $C(m+1,1)=C(m+1,m)=m+1$.